# Create a table like this

Tags: tables

How can I create a table like this:
[image]

I'm struggling with the header.

Comment: the `booktabs` package for better lines, `\multicolumn` for the headers.

Comment: This is a very poorly formulated question. Not searchable at all and shows no research effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will only look good as long as the data has the same size

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% not really needed since this is memoir
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
    \toprule
    $p=p_0$ 
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$n=10$}  
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$14$}  
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$20$}  
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$27$}  
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$50$}  
    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
    \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
    & 1 & 2
    & 1 & 2
    & 1 & 2
    & 1 & 2
    & 1 & 2
    \\    
    \midrule
    1.234 & 1.234 & 1.234 & 1.234 & 1.234 & 1.234 & 1.234 & 1.234 &
    1.234 & 1.234 & 1.234 
    \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've added some improvements for the caption and the font. Slightly changed the table header layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array, threeparttable, caption}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, labelsep=newline}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Exact sizes of the usual test (1) and the new test (2) when $α= 0.05$}
    \begin{tabular}{*{11}{l}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{r}{$n = $} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$10$}
                                 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$14$}
                                 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$20$}
                                 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$27$}
                                 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$50$}
      \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
      \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
      \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
      \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
      \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
      $p=p₀$ & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2
      \\
      \midrule
      0.05 & 0.012 & 0.012 & 0.004 & 0.030 & 0.016 & 0.016 & 0.010 & 0.044 & 0.012 & 0.038 \\
      0.10 & 0.013 & 0.013 & 0.009 & 0.044 & 0.011 & 0.043 & 0.015 & 0.047 & 0.030 & 0.030 \\
      0.15 & 0.010 & 0.050 & 0.012 & 0.047 & 0.022 & 0.022 & 0.026 & 0.026 & 0.027 & 0.044 \\
      0.20 & 0.006 & 0.033 & 0.012 & 0.044 & 0.022 & 0.044 & 0.030 & 0.049 & 0.033 & 0.049 \\
      0.25 & 0.020 & 0.020 & 0.028 & 0.010 & 0.038 & 0.017 & 0.042 & 0.042 & 0.033 & 0.048 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Might help you, at least the template I believe :)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Fill up the table for yourself :)}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllll}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{b} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{c} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{d} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{f} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{g} \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9} \cline{11-12} \cline{14-15} 
    & 1      & 2     &      & 1      & 2     &      & 1      & 2     &      & 1      & 2      &     & 1         & 2         \\ \hline
    1                     & 2      & 3     &      & 5      & 6     &      & 8      & 9     &      & 10     & 11     &     & 12        & 13        \\
    2                     & 2      & 3     &      & 5      & 6     &      & 8      & 9     &      & 10     & 11     &     & 12        & 13        \\
    3                     & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -      &     & -         & -         \\
    4                     & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -      &     & -         & -         \\
    5                     & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -      &     & -         & -         \\
    6                     & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -      &     & -         & -         \\
    7                     & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -      &     & -         & -         \\
    8                     & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -      &     & -         & -         \\
    9                     & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -      &     & -         & -         \\
    10                    & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -     &      & -      & -      &     & -         & -         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

to get as you wanted as in

[image]

Final note, make sure to fill up the table for yourself.

Comment: You might want to use the rules from `booktabs`, then the lines does not come so close to the data

Comment: @daleif Cool one, I never knew about that today. Thanks +1 for that :D

Answer (score 1):

If the table somehow fits in the text width, you can let TeX compute automatically the intercolumn space (but check whether it turns out to be too small).

I provide two solutions, one for entries that have the same number of digits, one for other cases, with `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Exact sizes of the usual test~(1) and the new test~(2) when $\alpha=0.05$}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l *{10}{c}
  @{}
}
\toprule
{$p=p_0$} &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$n=10$} &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$14$}   &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$20$}   &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$27$}   &
\multicolumn{2}{l@{}}{$50$}
\\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}\cmidrule{6-7}\cmidrule{8-9}\cmidrule{10-11}
&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{2}
\\
\midrule
0.05 & 0.012 & 0.012 & 0.004 & 0.030 & 0.016 & 0.016 & 0.010 & 0.044 & 0.012 & 0.038 \\
0.10 & 0.013 & 0.013 & 0.009 & 0.044 & 0.011 & 0.043 & 0.015 & 0.047 & 0.030 & 0.030 \\
0.15 & 0.010 & 0.050 & 0.012 & 0.047 & 0.022 & 0.022 & 0.026 & 0.026 & 0.027 & 0.044 \\
0.20 & 0.006 & 0.033 & 0.012 & 0.044 & 0.022 & 0.044 & 0.030 & 0.049 & 0.033 & 0.049 \\
0.25 & 0.020 & 0.020 & 0.028 & 0.010 & 0.038 & 0.017 & 0.042 & 0.042 & 0.033 & 0.048 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Exact sizes of the usual test~(1) and the new test~(2) when $\alpha=0.05$}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=1.2]
  *{10}{S[table-format=1.3]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
{$p=p_0$} &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$n=10$} &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$14$}   &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$20$}   &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$27$}   &
\multicolumn{2}{l@{}}{$50$}
\\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}\cmidrule{6-7}\cmidrule{8-9}\cmidrule{10-11}
&
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{2}
\\
\midrule
0.05 & 0.012 & 0.012 & 0.004 & 0.030 & 0.016 & 0.016 & 0.010 & 0.044 & 0.012 & 0.038 \\
0.10 & 0.013 & 0.013 & 0.009 & 0.044 & 0.011 & 0.043 & 0.015 & 0.047 & 0.030 & 0.030 \\
0.15 & 0.010 & 0.050 & 0.012 & 0.047 & 0.022 & 0.022 & 0.026 & 0.026 & 0.027 & 0.044 \\
0.20 & 0.006 & 0.033 & 0.012 & 0.044 & 0.022 & 0.044 & 0.030 & 0.049 & 0.033 & 0.049 \\
0.25 & 0.020 & 0.020 & 0.028 & 0.010 & 0.038 & 0.017 & 0.042 & 0.042 & 0.033 & 0.048 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I left out the formatting of the caption, that probably depends on the class you're using. With the `caption` package it's easy to format it as you please.

[image]